# Android App isn't creating Database / not finding it in File Explorer - DDMS

Tags: java, android

So, I've created an app which SHOULD be making a database. However, I've looked at the ADM and I've found it's not in there.

[image]

My confusion is why this is it not being created? I have:

1. DatabaseHandler.java
2. MyActivity.java
3. Car.java

I am calling methods from the *DatabaseHandler.java* inside the *MyActivity*. I have 0 errors in my project.

Here is my DatabaseHandler.java:

```
package com.example.brad.myapplication;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;

import static android.database.DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString;

/**
 * Created by Brad on 19/07/2014.
 */
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "carsGrid",
    TABLE_CARS = "cars",
    KEY_ID = "id",
    KEY_POSTCODE = "postcode",
    KEY_ADDRESS = "address",
    KEY_IMAGE = "image";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CARS + ")" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CARS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createCar(Car car) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, car.get_address());
        values.put(KEY_POSTCODE, car.get_postcode());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, car.get_image());

        db.insert(TABLE_CARS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Car getCar(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CARS, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_POSTCODE}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)}, null,null,null,null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Car car = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));
        return car;
    }

    public int getCarCount() {
        //SELECT * FROM CARS
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_CARS, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public String getRandomImageKey() {
        //SELECT * FROM CARS
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM" + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
        String toReturn = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        return toReturn;
    }

    public Car getCurrentCar() {

        SQLiteDatabase db       =   getWritableDatabase();
        String sql              =   "SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
        Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
        Car car = null;

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                car = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
                db.close();
        }
        return car;
    }

}
```

Here is my MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    // Defining elements in XML
    EditText postCodeStringTxt, DistanceNumberTxt, DebugCarTxt;
    String imagestring;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Creating elements in XML
        postCodeStringTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postCodeString);
        DistanceNumberTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DistanceNumber);
        DebugCarTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DebugCar);

        // you should  instantiate 'DatabaseHandler'  here
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); // "this" refer to the context
        Car cars = db.getCurrentCar();

        db.createCar(new Car(cars.get_id(),cars.get_address(),cars.get_postcode(),cars.get_image()));
        String rows= "id : "+ cars.get_id()+ " address : "+cars.get_address() + "postcode : "+cars.get_postcode()+" image : "+cars.get_image();
```

How can I zone into the area which isn't working if there are no errors in the project?

Comment: Post your `DatabaseHandler` class

Comment: Hi M D, it's the pastie link above.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Create `Table SQL Command` with below:

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CARS + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");
```

Your DB is not created it's because your create `Table SQL Command Syntax` is wrong.

You should also change this

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM" + TABLE_CARS + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
```

to

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);// make space after FROM and before ORDER BY
```

in your **getRandomImageKey()** method and also do same in **getCurrentCar()** method

Comment: Since making these changes my application "has stopped working" everytime I booted up.

Comment: @M D for some reason my logcat isn't producing anything

Comment: @BradlySpicer Then it's very difficult to identify ,where is the **problem** actually? but i think your issue is not related to this. I thought.

Comment: @BradlySpicer Issue is not about your App but about your `Emulator`. Just select the option from `DDMS-->Devics-->Top Right Corner click on menu-->adb reset`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57832/discussion-between-m-d-and-bradly-spicer).

Answer (score 2):

In your `DatabaseHandler` class create table syntax is wrong.so change this line

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CARS + ")" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");
```

into

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CARS + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");
```

As Frank suggest your two `rawQuery` statements are wrong give space after `FROM`

That too close `Cursor` after your opeariton is done.

Answer (score 1):

Not only your CREATE TABLE is wrong, as correctly pointed out by others (a reversed bracket and a missing space):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CARS + ")" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");
```

should be

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CARS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");
```

You have another issue here (missing a space):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_CARS, null);
```

should be

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARS, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

> db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CARS + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"+  KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE  + " TEXT)");

Answer (score 0):

> Try this..

```
String createTableQuery=String.format(
                "CREATE TABLE %s(%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%s TEXT,%s TEXT,%s TEXT)",
                TABLE_CARS, KEY_ID, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_POSTCODE, KEY_IMAGE);
```

....

```
dB.execSQL(createTableQuery);
```